# downloading php files tar

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I have a folder "a" with 10,000 php files in.  FTP is taking like forever.

I was thinking about zipping the folder somehow, then downloading that..

Do you know what command line I can use to zip it and unzip it?  I have linux ubuntu with sudo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command can be used to compress the folder:

```
tar czf /path/to/output/folder/filename.tar.gz /path/to/folder
```

And you can uncompress with:

```
tar xvzf target.tar.gz
```

Read up more on the [`tar man pages`](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html)

Answer (score 3):

Bundle/Compress: `tar czf a.tar.gz a/`

Decompress/Extract: `tar xzf a.tar.gz`

Comment: If you are downloading it onto a Windows system, 7zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) can unpack .tar /.gz files.

Answer (score 1):

- You could [compile PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.installation.php) with zip support?
- [using zip command:](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/blcmdl1_zipx.htm)

  zip -r archivefile1 .

  > This copies the current directory,
  >   including all subdirectories into the
  >   archive file.

## Example:

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ mkdir -p a
alfred@alfred-laptop:~$ cd a
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ echo "1" > 1
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ echo "2" > 2
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ mkdir -p b
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ cd b
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a/b$ echo "3" > 3
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a/b$ cd ..
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ zip -r a.zip .
  adding: 1 (stored 0%)
  adding: 2 (stored 0%)
  adding: b/ (stored 0%)
  adding: b/3 (stored 0%)
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ unzip a.zip -d unzipped
Archive:  a.zip
 extracting: unzipped/1              
 extracting: unzipped/2              
   creating: unzipped/b/
 extracting: unzipped/b/3
 alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a$ cd unzipped/
 alfred@alfred-laptop:~/a/unzipped$ ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 3 alfred alfred 4096 2011-02-02 13:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 alfred alfred 4096 2011-02-02 13:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 alfred alfred    2 2011-02-02 13:12 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 alfred alfred    2 2011-02-02 13:12 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 alfred alfred 4096 2011-02-02 13:13 b
```